# DOM Manipulation Click Mouse Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I was trying to change the color of the background of the web page with a mouse click, below are the lines for the same:

```js
let bodyvar = document.querySelector('body');

bodyvar.addEventListener("click",generate);

function generate(){
    bodyvar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

When I test individual lines in console it is selecting the body and the function and everything works correctly individually but not on the actual page.

I have just started leaning JS so am not sure what am missing here, will I also need to consider the co-ordinates that the mouse clicks on?

Comment: Please add your HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `<body></body>` is **empty**. Add some `content`, or define the `width` and `height`.

```js
let bodyvar = document.querySelector('body');
bodyvar.style.minWidth = "100vw";
bodyvar.style.minHeight = "100vh";

bodyvar.addEventListener("click",generate);

function generate(){
    bodyvar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

**Alternatively,** I can use `<HTML>` instead of `<body>`.

```js
let bodyvar = document.querySelector('html');

 bodyvar.addEventListener("click",generate);

 function generate(){
     bodyvar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
```